# $\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$ as a certain quotient of $\oplus_{k=0}^n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G=\oplus_{k=0}^n\mathbb{Z}a_k$ and $H=<a_0,2a_1-a_0,2a_2-a_1,...,2a_n-a_{n-1}>\subset G$

I need to prove that $G/H\cong \mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$, but I can't do it. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Try to use $G/H \simeq (G/K)/(H/K)$ (assuming everything makes sense). It will be better if you try for $n=1,2,3$ to get the idea before going for the general case.